# Collectd - Perl/Python plugin - registration functions not working

Tags: python, perl, plugins, registration, collectd

I would like to ask about Collectd's plugins Perl and Python and their registration functions.

I tried to code plugin in Perl (and also in Python), set up read and write functions and after that register them into Collectd (plugin_register functions). In all cases it wasnt working. Everytime, the logs show:

> Found a configuration for the "my_plugin" plugin, but the plugin
>   isn't loaded or didn't register a configuration callback.
>   severity=warning

I load my plugin in perl.conf.

Below I attach example of plugin which is directly from Collectd.perl documentation. This plugin, as well as my plugin, has the same result.

```
package Collectd::Plugins::FooBar;
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Collectd qw( :all );

  sub foobar_read
    {
    my $vl = { plugin => 'foobar', type => 'gauge' };
    $vl->{'values'} = [ rand(42) ];
    plugin_dispatch_values ($vl);
    return 1;
    }
  sub foobar_write
    {
    my ($type, $ds, $vl) = @_;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar (@$ds); ++$i) {
      print "$vl->{'plugin'} ($vl->{'type'}): $vl->{'values'}->[$i]\n";
    }
    return 1;
    }

  sub foobar_match
    {
    my ($ds, $vl, $meta, $user_data) = @_;
    if (matches($ds, $vl)) {
      return FC_MATCH_MATCHES;
    } else {
      return FC_MATCH_NO_MATCH;
    }
    }

  plugin_register (TYPE_READ, "foobar", "foobar_read");
  plugin_register (TYPE_WRITE, "foobar", "foobar_write");
  fc_register (FC_MATCH, "foobar", "foobar_match");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your configuration if you can.

The documentation says that the ***`LoadPlugin`*** configuration goes in the collectd.conf file (not that that seems to matter in your case from your log file).

Put your foobar.pm module at ***`/path/to/perl/plugins/Collectd/Plugins/FoorBar.pm`*** matching it with the path that you specified ... (match the case of names of plugin and plugin pm file).

```
LoadPlugin perl
# ...
<Plugin perl>
  IncludeDir "/path/to/perl/plugins"
  BaseName "Collectd::Plugins"
  EnableDebugger ""
  LoadPlugin "FooBar"

  <Plugin FooBar>
    Foo "Bar"
  </Plugin>
</Plugin>
```

Comment: I use the command `LoadPlugin name_of_my_plugin` . Because it is my own plugin, so I need somehow register functions/method there, but I wasnt successful in it in spite of the documentation instructions.

Comment: Unfortunalety not. With the DBI plugin and Postgres database - it ends on this log:
`dbi plugin: cdbi_connect_database: dbi_driver_open_r (Pg) failed. severity=err`

Comment: I hope that it works now. The driver is not Pg but pgsql. Thank you

Comment: Check if you are able to connect it postgres db from outside, on command-line using Perl. If that is the case, then you may need to replicate the same PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH to your collectd server (In order to possibly find the correct postgres library).